# What is the underlying programming language used in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm experimenting with Azure Data Factory and building pipelines.

I want to know what language is ADF built upon. I see that a pipeline's properties are saved in JSON but what programming language actually parses through the JSON to build the pipeline?

I can't find documentation for this. Any related links would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Data Factory version 1, you implement a (Custom) DotNet Activity by creating a .NET Class Library project with a class that implements the Execute method of the IDotNetActivity interface. The Linked Services, Datasets, and Extended Properties in the JSON payload of a (Custom) DotNet Activity are passed to the execution method as strongly-typed objects. For details about the version 1 behavior, see (Custom) DotNet in version 1. Because of this implementation, your version 1 DotNet Activity code has to target .NET Framework 4.5.2. The version 1 DotNet Activity also has to be executed on Windows-based Azure Batch Pool nodes.

In the Azure Data Factory V2 and Synapse pipelines Custom Activity, you are not required to implement a .NET interface. You can now directly run commands, scripts, and your own custom code, compiled as an executable. To configure this implementation, you specify the Command property together with the folderPath property. The Custom Activity uploads the executable and its dependencies to folderpath and executes the command for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. But my question is about the specific language ADF runs upon. I'm sure there is a programming language that backs the pipelines. Any idea which language that is?                                                                                                                                      In a tutorial that I watched, they mentioned it was Scala but I didn't find any docs to support this.

Comment: I’m not a dev but if ADF is like other services in Azure it’s composed of multiple micro services all developed in their own languages.  I doubt there is one single language for the entire service.  Is there a particular issue you are trying to solve that knowing the underlying language would solve?